# How to check all records that are in SQL server, exist in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

**Summary of the problem**

I have a Python Script that gets data from SQL Server and inserts it into MySQL database.

In order to keep up to date information I do the following actions:

1. Truncate the table
2. Insert data taken from SQL Server.

Without the truncate, It'll just add stacks of duplicate data on top of each other in MySQL database.

**Question**

How can I only `insert` values from SQL server to MySQL table - only the records that do not already exist between the 2 databases? In other words, how do I check if SQL server record already exists in MySQL? If it does exist, then do not `insert` and go to next record.

I need to get rid of using `truncate`.

**Current code:**

```
########## FUNCTIONS TO DELETE ALL MYSQL TABLES ########## 

def truncateMJM():
    #Mjm table
    truncateMJMCursor = productionConnection.cursor()
    truncateMJMCursor.execute("Truncate MJM")
    truncateMJMCursor.close()
    productionConnection.commit()

########## FUNCTIONS TO DELETE ALL MYSQL TABLES END ########## 

########## START UP FUNCTION ########## 
def start():

    print("Deleting MySQL tables")
    truncateMJM()

     #Get data from SQL
    sqlCursor = mjmConnection.cursor()
    sqlCursor.execute("SELECT p.id, p.code,p.description, p.searchRef1, so.number, c.code, c.name, sol.requiredQty \
         FROM salesorderline sol JOIN \
         salesorder so \
         ON sol.salesorderid = so.id JOIN \
         product p \
         ON sol.productid = p.id JOIN \
         customer c \
         ON so.customerid = c.id \
         WHERE so.orderdate > DATEADD(dd,-35,CAST(GETDATE() AS date));")

    #Send recieved data from SQL query from above to MySQL database
    print("Sending records to MySQL Database")
    mjmCursorMysql = productionConnection.cursor()
    for x in sqlCursor.fetchall():
        a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = x
        mjmCursorMysql.execute("INSERT INTO mjm (product_id, product_code, product_description, product_weight, \
                salesorder_number, customer_code, customer_name, requiredQty) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);", (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h))
```

Comment: Can you create a candidate key in the target table that will automagically exclude duplicate rows?

Comment: @nicomp Do you mean, `id` number? If so, I can take the `id` number from the `SQL Server`..

Comment: I don't know what your candidate keys are, but if id number is one, ok.

Comment: @nicomp Then I'll just do a check if this `id` number exists ?

Comment: I wouldn't, rather I would just add all the rows and let the RDBMS refuse to add the duplicate keys. Of course, I don 't have the perspective on your system that you do.

Comment: @nicomp I see .. but if it refused.. wouldn't the Python script break?

Comment: Not if you trap errors and recover properly.

Comment: @nicomp I see your point.. I'll get something drafter up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added new foreign key column in MySQL and also taken `id` numbers from SQL server. This will prevent duplication in MySQL side.

Finally, I have used the following query in Python:

```
INSERT ignore INTO
```

No other adjustments in my current code. Expect for taking out the `truncate` funcitons.